# The right way to use cgroups to restrict cpu usage

Tags: linux, cgroups

I follow the red hat documents to create three groups for three users using command:

```
cgcreate -t uid:gid -a uid:gid -g subsystems:group
```

Say user A,B,C belong to group 1,2,3 respectively.

But using this method, A can modify the cpu.shares file to set a very large number so he can take more cpu shares from B and C. 
I don't think this is the right way to create group, any suggestion?

Besides, even the groups are created, if any user run their processes without using cgexec, will the restriction fails? Will the system put these processes to any group (a default one maybe)? If so, what is the behavior of the default group?

Comment: This would better asked on the http://unix.stackexchange.com/ site. I do cgroup cpu on embedded systems, using simple `mkdir` and `echo` commands (and down to the basics, that all CPU cgroup actually need) . But if you want to use `cgmanager `and its tools, on a regular full-blown Linux distro, basic stackoverflow.com is not the way to go to ask for help.

Comment: ..."using simple `mkdir` and `echo` commands" AND `mount` first of course (to mount the cgroup CPU), I might add.